# How to change file types?

Tags: command-line, permissions, file-type

I changed the permissions of some directories and the files within them, so now when I list them, most are highlighted green or have names that are green.

Some of the files used to be blue or white, and I need to change them back to those types of files. How do I do this, and how would I do it recursively?

Comment: Which command did you run exactly? But be aware that directly reversing that command doesn't mean you'll get back to where you started from. For example if a directory wasn't writable by others it would have shown as sky blue: if your command set both the writable and, say, executable bit for that directory, reversing the command could remove the executable bit inappropriately in case it was set before the wrong command was run (or the other way, not removing it could leave it inappropriately in case it wasn't).

Comment: I ran
"chmod 777 -R"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -R option will run that command on each and every file/folder it finds below your current folder.
run `chmod go-w -R` from wherever you ran that command for safety; and stop other users/groups re-writting any files that don't belong to them.
In most cases this is OK but you may have to edit specific files if you have problems, I just hope you didn't run it from /

-R is dangerous. see `man chmod` for options or [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod)